# Base class function gets called twice

Tags: c++, class, oop

I have a base class and a derived class. I want to let to user decide when to `free()` the memory allocated by both classes, and these functions will also be called by the classes' destructors.

However, this approach forces the base class `free()` function to be called twice, the first time from the derived class `free()` function, and the second time from the base destructor.

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {
        _baseVal = new int(4);
        cout << "base constructor\n";
    }

    virtual void free()
    {
        if(_baseVal) {
            delete _baseVal;
            _baseVal = 0;
        }
        cout << "base free()\n";
    }

    virtual ~Base() {
        free();
    }


private:
    int *_baseVal;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() {
        _derivedVal = new int(10);
        cout << "derived constructor\n";
    }

    void free()
    {
        Base::free();

        if(_derivedVal) {
            delete _derivedVal;
            _derivedVal = 0;
        }
        cout << "derived free()\n";
    }

    ~Derived() {
        free();
    }


private:
    int *_derivedVal;
};


int main()
{
    Base *der = new Derived;
    delete der;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
base constructor
derived constructor
base free()
derived free()
base free()
```

Is there any way for this approach that doesn't force the base `free()` to be called twice?

Comment: Don't call `Base::free()` from `Derived::free()`.

Comment: But what if the user wants to keep using the instance? Perhaps reallocate the integers' memory. I didn't write an `allocate()` function so things wouldn't get more complicated.

Comment: keep using it after destruction??

Comment: Just read your comment after posting my answer. How do you mean "wants to keep using the instance"? The instance of what, Derived or the _baseVal integer?

Comment: The instance of Derived. I might want to just call `der->free()` and then keep using `der`. As I said there should be a `reallocate()` function that I just didn't write. Sorry but I didn't mention that in my project, I must call `Base::free()` from `Derived::free()`.

Comment: This sounds contradictory: You must call the base function from the derived one, but you want to be able to call the derived one without calling the base one. You could work around this by giving `Derived::free` an extra boolean parameter flagging whether you want to clean up the base value as well, but that is a really bad code smell to me. It sounds like the problem you are having is not with C++ itself, but with the design of your code?

Comment: If `Base` was an abstract class, simply omitting the `free()` call from its destructor will do the trick, because the base `free()` will be called anyway by the derived destructor. However this will cause memory leaks if `Base` isn't abstract and a class of `Base` would be instantiated and destroyed. In my project, the base class is abstract so I'll stick with this solution...

Comment: That sounds like a dangerous plan. As I stated in my answer, calling `free()` more than once does not hurt. Anyway, it is really not clear to me what you want exactly and since you seem to be really focused on this technical issue rather than explain what it is you are trying to achieve on a higher level, I'll just leave it at this.

Comment: In my project, the base class is called `BaseImage`, which is an abstract class that holds a pointer called `pixels` which points to data allocated on the heap. The derived class is called `PNGImage`, and it has some heap allocated data too. It makes no sense to free `PNGImage`'s data without freeing `BaseImage::pixels` as well, therefore I must call `BaseImage::free()` inside `PNGImage::free()`.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor is not called twice, but `Base::free()` is called twice. The difference is important, because the latter is your own class method. The destructor is called by the compiler and is called once and only once.

When the `Derived` object goes out of scope, first its own destructor is called. In `Derived::~Derived` you call `Derived::free()`. The first thing you do there, is call `Base::free()`. Then you handle the rest of your derived class logic. When the `Derived` part has been cleaned up, the destructor for the `Base` part is executed which by itself calls `Base::free()`.

In principle you don't have a problem here, because you made sure that `Base::free()` doesn't do anything if it has already run (by setting `_baseVal` to a null pointer). You can avoid it by removing the call to `Base::free()` from `Derived::free()` however, since the `Base` destructor will guarantee that `Base::free()` will run at least once.